# Attaching a different compiler other than GCC to Clion IDE on Windows

Tags: c++, cmake, clion

I am developing with Clion and minigw-w64. The IDE uses cmake.

I discovered a bug in GCC that is forcing me to switch compilers, I have no choice. The bug has to do with how gcc handles stack alignment. Clion seems to only support minigw and cygwin on windows, which I believe are both tool sets that use the gcc compiler.

Is there an easy way to get Clion / cmake to use a different compiler? I've read that clang is very similar to GCC because it accepts the same compiler flags, so I wonder if this might be a good alternative. I've also read you can change the compiler that cmake uses just by changing some flags, but I don't know in which file to put this, or if changing this will break compatibility with Clion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [CLion's FAQ](http://blog.jetbrains.com/clion/2014/09/clion-answers-frequently-asked-questions/)

> At present CLion supports GCC and Clang compilers and is guided by these two to get the libraries and headers paths. In the next releases we are planning to extend the list of compilers available in CLion.
>   To change the compiler, go to the Cache tab in CMake tool window and set the compiler’s path to the `CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER` variable. Then press Enter and click the Apply Changes and Reload button:

[image]

> Search our issue tracker for feature requests about supporting other compilers to follow or vote on them, or add a new one if it’s missing.

Comment: I can't get this to work. Cmake wont compile. In addition to what you said, I also tried setting the linker and other parameters to the clang counterparts, still didn't work

Comment: Exactly what problem do you get? Have you installed `clang`?

Comment: @MatsPetersson error: the c++ compiler "clang++.exe path here" is not able to compile a simple test program. This happens when I try to update the cmake cache arguments.